# Geolocalizacion en HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Presiona el botón para obtener tus coordenadas.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocalización no es soportada por tu navegador.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitud: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitud: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo quito el botón y hago que automáticamente me ponga la latitud y la longitud en un campo de texto?

Comment: puse un echo pero no lo logré

<?php echo position.coords.latitude >

Comment: En tu pregunta no se mencionada nada sobre php. Si es relevante para lo que tienes hacer deberías mencionarlo así como también que has intentado con respecto a lo que estas preguntando que en este caso son formas de quitar el botón y agregar las coordenadas a un campo de texto.

Comment: Pues es lo unico que intente pero no lo logre

Comment: Si no lo has hecho aún lee [ask].

Comment: que foro tan poco util y no se para que se toman la molestia de leer para al final poner "Si no lo has hecho aún lee Cómo preguntar."

Comment: Bueno si no hay quien me responda mi duda pues gracias por nada

Comment: Ya que estás aprendiendo como funciona el sitio, deberías saber que cuando alguien te responde (como en las otras preguntas que tienes) deberías marcar la respuesta correcta como aceptada. Que aquí **no estás a las órdenes de nadie** y **nadie tiene ninguna obligación contigo**, y menos si tú no intentas hacer las preguntas tal como se establecen las normas y solo buscas que alguien te haga tu trabajo. Saludos.

Comment: Hay muchas personas que pueden responder tu pregunta, pero tu actitud incomoda  y quita la voluntad de asistirte. No te importan las reglas del sitio y solo buscas beneficio propio; lo siento amigo, esto no funciona así. Como mínimo, debes leer las reglas del sitio, las FAQ, las guía de ayuda para que uses correctamente el sitio; no puedes entrar a una casa, sentarte, poner los pies sobre la mesa y decir «oigan ayúdenme». Tienes una pregunta del **9 de junio, la cual no te tomaste ni la molestia para marcar la respuesta correcta**. ¿Cómo puedes venir tan suelto y decir «gracias por nada»?

Comment: no me permite marcar respuestas coorectas, dice que porque no tengo cierto puntos

Comment: @GustavoGarcía El autor de la pregunta si desea marca una respuesta como correcta o sino no, no tiene la obligación de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función es correcta, si entendí bien lo que quieres es que funcione cuando se cargue la página y no cuando se toque el botón, verdad?

Esto lo puedes lograr de varias formas, una que yo usaría, es esperar que todo el contenido del dom este cargado y ahí llamar a la función.

Algo así usando tu código:

```
var x = null; 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    x = document.getElementById("demo");
    getLocation();
  });

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocalización no es soportada por tu navegador.";
    }

}

function showPosition(position) {
        if(x != null)
    {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitud: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitud: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
}
```

Y en realidad eso es todo, pruebalo, reemplaza lo que tienes dentro de `<script></script>` por eso y cuando cargues tu página las coordenadas van a aparecer solas.

Comment: En [answer] se recomienda responder sólo las preguntas bien formadas. En particular, la solicitudes de aclaraciones y las críticas (todas deben ser constructivas) se deberían realizar en comentarios, no en las respuestas.

Comment: Me faltó mencionar que para poder [realizar comentarios en publicaciones de otros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) se requiere de 50 puntos de reputación.

Comment: @Rubén mas allá de que se enojo y que la etiqueta PHP estaba demás ( explico porque la había puesto),  me parece que a la pregunta no le hace falta más descripción. Se entiende lo que quería lograr y adjunte una porción de código que vendría a solucionar eso. Debería el probarla a ver si le sirve.